# Cron4j pattern matching precise hour while it shouldn't

Tags: cronexpression, cron4j

Please consider the following code

```
String pattern = "*/17 * * * *";
Date d = new Date();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Start: " + d + ", " + (d = new Predictor(pattern, d).nextMatchingDate()));
}
```

This outputs the following sample (I put the times I didn't expect between brackets):

```
Start: Tue Jun 11 12:54:48 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 (13:00:00) GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 13:00:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 13:17:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 13:17:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 13:34:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 13:34:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 13:51:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 13:51:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 (14:00:00) GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 14:00:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 14:17:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 14:17:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 14:34:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 14:34:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 14:51:00 GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 14:51:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 (15:00:00) GMT+02:00 2013
Start: Tue Jun 11 15:00:00 GMT+02:00 2013, Tue Jun 11 15:17:00 GMT+02:00 2013
```

Although the pattern is configured to match minutes divisible by 17, if that's a correct way to describe it, the predictor considers a precise hour (13:00, 14:00, 15:00..etc) a valid next-matching-date !

My questions are:

- Is this behavior valid ? If yes, then why is it valid ?
- How can I prevent this behavior ? I mean how can I prevent the predictor from considering a precise hour as a matching time if the time field (i.e. minutes, hours, days, week day) isn't divisible by it's maximum value (i.e. 60, 24, 30 or 31, 7) ?
- Is this actually the case with unix cron scheduling ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this context `0` and `*` are interchangable.  So it will run on the hour and then at 17 minute intervals during the hour.

To start at 17 minutes past the hour and then at that duration try this pattern: `17-59/17 * * * *`

Comment: Is that the case for the Unix cron scheduler ? Thanks for the pattern but all the next-matching times are at the minute 17 only (i.e. 18:17, 19:17, 20:17..etc)

Comment: Yes that is for unix cron.  I must admit that I have not used cron4j but the quartz schedluer cron bean instead.

Comment: You could try "17-59/17 * * * *" as that range syntax may be supported

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic method. Something that I don't need to process using code so it would just work.

Comment: According to the cron4j documentation it does support a range. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I guess that so far, the answer is that this is just how Cron4j works. If I need to avoid hitting the 00 minutes if the minutes specified isn't divisible by 60, then I'll have to perform extra processing and do as you mentioned (17-59, 7-23 for */7 hours as not to hit midnight, etc). I need to perform this as easily and reliably as possible to avoid major code re-factoring. I was hoping that cron scheduling patterns support this somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. That is the cron pattern. But yes you would need to determine that for minutes the range is up to 59, and hours it is 23 etc if you are generating the pattern programmatically.

Comment: I'm basically asking for a generic/standard way to solve the problem. */17 is just an example. I need to be able to solve */5 and */17 cases in a standard way (If there is any) so I don't have to modify my code and of course avoid new bugs/issues in the future. I'm constructing the pattern from user input fields and it's a very complicated process.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.cronmaker.com/ Internally it uses the quartz library to construct the cron expression from user input. You may be able to do something similar.